# How do I add a variable id belonging to each form post to localStorage everytime I submit a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this task of creating a form that whenever submitted, saves its values in **localStorage**, and **displays all the data sent in an adjacent table** holding each submitted form data.

This I managed to successfully code via pushing each value to an array of all the values of its corresponding field and saving it in localStorage.

What I'm having a hard time with is also saving an incremented id to localStorage.

i.e. the first submitted form has an id of 0, second has an id of 1 and so on, all stored in an ids array that's saved in localStorage.

> **This is required so that I have an edit/delete function that uses each form's id in order to work.**

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Here is my code

```
//arrays of each data field
let firstnames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('firstnames') || '[]');
let lastnames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastnames') || '[]');
let ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id') || '[]');

//array of all stored data
let data = JSON.stringify([firstnames, lastnames, ids]);

function validate() {
//retrieve all form elements
let fn = document.form.firstname;
let ln = document.form.lastname;
let p = document.getElementById('warn');

//validate entered data and check constraints
if (fn.value === "") {
    p.innerHTML = "Please enter your first name!";
    fn.focus();
    return false;
}
if (ln.value === "") {
    p.innerHTML = "Please enter your last name!";
    ln.focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}

function* idMaker() {
let id = 1;
while (true) {
    yield id++;
}
}



window.onload = function () {

if (localStorage) { // Check for LocalStorage support.

    // Add an event listener for form submissions.
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function () {


        //placeholder paragraph division to warn the user that the form is 
incomplete.
        let p = document.getElementById("incomplete");

        if (validate() == true) {

            //retrieve form field values.
            let fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
            let lname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;

            let pid = idMaker();

            firstnames.push(fname);
            lastnames.push(lname);
            ids.push(JSON.stringify(pid.next().value));




            //store the entered data inside localStorage in JSON format.
            localStorage.setItem('firstnames', JSON.stringify(firstnames));
            localStorage.setItem('lastnames', JSON.stringify(lastnames));
            localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(ids));
        } else {
            p.innerHTML = "Please complete the form before submitting any data!";
        }
    });
}

//table that will show each individual form submission.
let posts = document.getElementById("posts");

//retrieve stored data and output it to the posts table.
let retFname = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('firstnames'));
let retLname = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastnames'));
let postID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id'));

for (let i = 0; i < firstnames.length; i++) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("firstnames") != null) {
        posts.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr><td>' + 'Name: ' + retFname[i] + ' ' + retLname[i] + '</td><td><button type="button" onclick="editOrDelete(' + postID[i] + ')">Edit/Delete</button></td></tr>');
    } else {
        posts.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Nothing yet!');
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why not save the id in the array?

Comment: share your code

Comment: I want to save the id in an array, but using the present generator, it just keeps adding 1 to the id array.

@Ash I just did, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @AlaaHoussamy try to make your code relevant to your question to make it faster to read, for example just having firstname and lastname is enough to get to the point there is no need for everyone to go through the whole code

Comment: you need to put everything in one array, e.g users = [{name:ash, food:['chicken', 'beef'] }, {}]

Comment: @Ash I have reduced the code to make it faster to read and left the relevant fields.

Comment: I think it will be efficient if you save the fields in localStorage by putting them in an array of object. Did you try my solution?

Comment: I made a little change to your code to make it more readable I hope it answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to achieve autoincrement id in each object in array taking the reference to the following code. In my code I have used 'name', 'address' and 'phone' input fields in HTML which have id 'name', 'address' and 'phone'. The form has an id 'form'. I used 'storedValues' as the name given to the stored data.

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', callFuntion);


function callFuntion() {
    let obj = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        address: document.getElementById('address').value,
        phone: document.getElementById('phone').value
    };
    let array = localStorage.getItem('storedValues') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedValues')) : [];
    obj.id = array.length;  //if first submit, it gives id = 0 as array is empty, if second, it gives id = 1 as array with one element is pushed in local storage
    array.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem('storedValues', JSON.stringify(array));
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it and it's now working. Thank you so much Niraj! Lifesaver.

Comment: You are welcome. Keep on doing good work. I don't know somebody downvoted my answer. If you could upvote it as well, it would be appreciable. Thanks. :)

Comment: Probably some fool...
I already upvoted but I don't have enough reputation for it to show :(